# График в mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, график

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как привести в порядок график? В `df[Income]` у меня 5000 значений и график получается страшным. Можно ли как-то разбить `df[Income]` на группы или разграничить цифры по оси Х?

```py
df['Income'].describe()
```

```
-count    5.000000e+03
-mean     2.067813e+06
-std      1.315743e+06
-min      0.000000e+00
-25%      1.075706e+06
-50%      1.783408e+06
-75%      2.774190e+06
-max      6.341005e+06
-Name: Income, dtype: float64
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKl9D.png]

```py
%matplotlib inline  
pd.crosstab(df["Income"],df['Personal Credit']).plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('Acceptance the Personal Credit for Income') 
plt.xlabel('Income') 
plt.ylabel('Frequency of Acceptance the Personal Credit') 
plt.savefig('income_bar_chart')
```

Comment: Тут скорее histplot или displot нужен из seaborn, мне кажется. А может даже просто kind="hist" сработает

Comment: Есть вариант с масштабированием, типа data=data[::step] и взаимодействие для выбора масштаба и участка допустим с клавиатурой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы разбил график на блоки из отдельных графиков, если нужно более детально изучить данные, но в целом ты можешь просто изменить тики по оси x.

```
plt.xticks(array)
```

Где в переменной array лежат твои отсчёты по оси.
Также можно сделать по оси y.

Comment: Да просто barplot для такого анализа не подходит, он хорош для категориальной переменной по одной из осей, а тут обе оси числовые.